# Калькулятор - некорректная сумма через for

Tags: javascript, html

Вот смотрите есть такой калькулятор

```
    <input type="text" value="0" id="q1">
    <input type="button" value="sss" onclick="func()">
    <div id="qq"></div>
    <script>
        function func(){
        var x = new Number (document.getElementById('q1').value);
        var f = document.getElementById('qq');    
        var z = 3;
        var m = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<z;i++){
            if (i % 2 == 0){
                 m = m + x * 2;
                console.log(m);
                     //resvkl3 = sum*0.11/365*91; alert(resvkl3); 
            }else{
                 m = m + x * 2;
                  console.log(m);    //resvkl3 = sum*0.11/365*91; alert(resvkl3);
            }
        }
        f.innerHTML = m;    
        }
</script>
```

Введем в инпут 2 и в консоле будет 4,8,12. Т.е. калькуль берёт 2 умножает на 2, затем получившуюся 4 умножает на 2 получается 8, а вот затем....Почему он не 8 умножает на 2, а 4 умножает на 2 и прибовляет к 8? И как это исправить?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов То, что вы делаете, то вы и получаете. В чем проблема? Вы к m прибавляете 2 * 2, то есть к очередному значению m вы прибавляете 4.

Comment: Господа, минуту, я пытаюсь перефразировать

Comment: Непонятно, какой результат вам необходим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый шаг: `0 + 2 * 2 = 4`

Второй шаг: `4 + 2 * 2 = 8`

Третий шаг: `8 + 2 * 2 = 12`

Не совсем понятно, что Вы хотите получить, если Вам что-то не нравится.

Замечания по коду: возможно, это промежуточный вариант, но в

```
        if (i % 2 == 0){
             m = m + x * 2;
            console.log(m);
                 //resvkl3 = sum*0.11/365*91; alert(resvkl3); 
        }else{
             m = m + x * 2;
              console.log(m);    //resvkl3 = sum*0.11/365*91; alert(resvkl3);
        }
```

`if` не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки, можно просто сделать:

```
m = m + x * 2;
console.log(m);
```

Вы писали

> затем получившуюся 4 умножает на 2 получается 8

Это не так. 8 получается так: `4+2*2`, здесь Вы скорее всего ошиблись в значении переменных. Намного лучше для Вас же, если Вы будете называть их более осмысленно, типа `sum`, `lastResult` и т.д.

Скажите, что Вы хотите получить в итоге?